# Combobox partial refresh issue

Tags: xpages

after some down time I'm back again doing some xpages and I already seem to have forgotton to many things. I have the following code:

A datasource:

```xml
<xe:objectData var="league" ignoreRequestParams="true" scope="request">
    <xe:this.saveObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:leagueService.set(league)}]]></xe:this.saveObject>
    <xe:this.createObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:return leagueService.get(viewScope.currentKey);}]]></xe:this.createObject>
</xe:objectData>
```

and a couple of comboboxes

```xml
    <xp:comboBox id="idLeagueList" value="#{viewScope.currentKey}">
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript: return eu.jeroensomhorst.cms.util.JSFUtil.asSelectItem(leagueService.getAll(season),true);}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>   
        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="complete"></xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:comboBox>

    <xp:listBox id="lstAvailableTeams">
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:eu.jeroensomhorst.cms.util.JSFUtil.asSelectItem(teamService.getAll());}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>
    </xp:listBox>
```

and a button which adds selected teams in the lstAvailableTeams to the selected leage object

```xml
    <xp:button value="&#62;" id="addTeam" >
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" disableValidators="true">
                    <xp:this.action>
                        <xp:actionGroup>
                            <xp:executeScript>
                                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var teamList = getComponent("lstAvailableTeams");
    var strTeamKey = teamList.getValue();
    eu.jeroensomhorst.cms.util.LeagueUtil.addTeam(league.getKey(),strTeamKey);}]]></xp:this.script>
                            </xp:executeScript>
                        </xp:actionGroup>
                    </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>

    <xp:listBox id="leagueTeams">
            <xp:selectItems>
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return eu.jeroensomhorst.cms.util.JSFUtil.asSelectItem(league.getTeams());}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:selectItems>
    </xp:listBox>
```

the code of the leagueutil looks like this:

```java
public static void addTeam(String leagueKey,String key){
    LeagueService lService = (LeagueService) DominoUtil.getVariableValue("leagueService");

    League l = (League) lService.get(leagueKey);
    TeamService service = (TeamService) DominoUtil.getVariableValue("teamService");
    Team t = service.get(key);
    Vector<Team> teams = l.getTeams();
    if(teams == null){
        teams = new Vector();
        teams.add(t);
    }else{
        if(!teams.contains(t)){
            teams.add(t);
        }
    }

    l.setTeams(teams);
    // save into database.. this works.
    lService.set(l);

}
```

as you can see nothing to fancy. But the problem is as followes. Whenever I do a change of the idLeagueList combobox values and execute the changelistener (it updates the viewscope ). It always retrieves the previous values which are displayed in the leagueteams combobox. It is a really basic question but I'm totally out of options..

Comment: Could it be that your scopes are different, you objectData is set to 'request', and your comboboxes are using 'viewScope', try changing your objectData to 'view'.

Comment: I've tried that and that's not the problem here. When the objectdata is set to viewscope nothing changes because the partial refresh doesn't retrieve the datasource again. When the scope of the combobox is changed no change is seen at all

Comment: updated the code so it reflects the issue. The issue is that whenever I change the value of the idLeagueList the data that is shown in the other comboboxes is not refreshed but always one step behind.

Comment: Whenever your functionality is "one step behind", your problem is in JSF lifecycle. Double check what computes at what phase.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will add a phaselistener soon.

Answer (score 2):

`createObject` of `objectData` gets executed too early: before the restore view phase is completed. This way `objectData` gets the old value from `viewScope.currentKey`.

```
createObject:           viewScope.currentKey = old value
afterRestoreView:       viewScope.currentKey = old value
beforeRenderResponse:   viewScope.currentKey = new value
```

A possible way to solve your issue is to use a view scope variable for league object instead. You can set it in `beforePageLoad` and `beforeRenderResponse` events.

```
viewScope.league = leagueService.get(viewScope.currentKey)
```

and use it in listBox

```
... eu.jeroensomhorst.cms.util.JSFUtil.asSelectItem(viewScope.league.getTeams())
```

and button code

```
... eu.jeroensomhorst.cms.util.LeagueUtil.addTeam(viewScope.league.getKey(),strTeamKey)
```

Here is a short version of your code for test purposes. It shows the current value of `viewScope.currentKey` at several JSF phases with print statements:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.afterRestoreView><![CDATA[#{javascript:print ("afterRestoreView: " + viewScope.currentKey)}]]></xp:this.afterRestoreView>
    <xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:print ("beforeRenderResponse: " + viewScope.currentKey)}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
    <xp:this.afterRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:print ("afterRenderResponse: " + viewScope.currentKey)}]]></xp:this.afterRenderResponse>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xe:objectData
            var="league"
            ignoreRequestParams="true"
            scope="request">
            <xe:this.createObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                if (viewScope.currentKey == null) viewScope.currentKey = "aaa"; 
                print("createObject: " + viewScope.currentKey); 
                viewScope.currentKey}]]>
            </xe:this.createObject>
        </xe:objectData>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:comboBox
        id="idLeagueList"
        value="#{viewScope.currentKey}">
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript: return ["aaa","bbb"];}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onchange"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:comboBox>
    <xp:listBox
        id="leagueTeams">
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                print("listBox: league = " + league + " viewScope.currentKey=" + viewScope.currentKey); 
                if (league === "aaa") return ["aaa1","aaa2"]; else return ["bbb1","bbb2"]}]]>
            </xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>
    </xp:listBox>
</xp:view>
```